# How do I disable a plugin in mobile view?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using a plugin that add comments to iframes that isn't responsive, so I would like to turn off the plugin in mobile view. How do I target the plugin for that? when I googled around this seemed to be the answer, but not sure how to target my plugin.

```
if (!wp_is_mobile()) { 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think disabling the plugin would be a solution in your case, because plugins are not customized to enabled and disabled for specific view.
Better idea would be to create a function in your function.php file and fire it when comment is loaded and just ignore when user is viewing in mobile else load the comments in iframe.

Can't proceed further with your given information.